# user input in Adruino serial monitor

Tags: arduino

i don't know how to ask the user for a string input to the serial monitor that you can  change when the program is running

I tried deferend commands and even searched for videos on youtube but didn't get the selution i wanted

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `Serial.readStringUntil(char terminator)` function as shown in the [reference](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstringuntil/). It reads a String from the Serial interface until either the timeout set by [setTimeout](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/settimeout/) (Default: 1000 ms, so 1 second) or the terminating character is found.

Your problem might be that you are running into the timeout.
To avoid this, you can:

1. Set the timeout to a higher value. (60 seconds, for example)
2. Wait for data to be available before starting to read by using the [Serial.available](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/available/) function. (Thanks to Juraj for pointing this out)
   If you do this however, keep in mind, that the loop will continue on running, and doesn't block the execution of code until data is actually entered.

This is a short example of how you might use these functions:

```cpp
void setup() {
    // Starts the serial interface with 9600 Baud
    // you might use a different baud rate.
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Set the timeout to one minute.
    Serial.setTimeout(60000);

    Serial.println("Please enter some text.");
}
    
void loop() {
    // Check if data is a available, then read it.
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        String input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println("You entered: " + input);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Juraj thank you for the suggestion! I changed the Answer accordingly.